# how to have ability to load parameters in constructor and "by event"?

Tags: c#, oop

During object construction I should initialize several parameters. As an example

```
Vehicle (color)
     I
Car (transmission type, air conditioning (boolean))
     I
Cabriolet (roof (boolean))
```

I also need ability to `Reload` all parameters at any time (because my parameters are actually changable). I was thinking to create `virtual ReloadParameters()` method for each class which will call `super` and load this class parameters.

The problem is that I also need to load all parameters during construction and I don't want to call virtual method from constructor because this is bad practice.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the need to Reload? Not sure what you mean by "class parameters".

Comment: @ErenErsönmez this class parameters is color for Vehicle, transmission type for Car etc. I need ability to reload everything when object is already constructed as well as I need to load parameters during construction.

Comment: To reduce (but not eliminate) duplication, each class could have a private `LoadParameters` method; both the constructor and the virtual `ReloadParameters` method could call the private method.  But I suspect that the better solution would be another approach entirely; I'm just not clear enough on the meaning of the "parameters are actually changeable" requirement to suggest another approach.  Why, how, and when would the parameters change?

Comment: @phoog all parameters are in text file. they may change while program works. so I just click "reload" to load up to date data.

Comment: Could you just create new objects with the new data and discard the old ones?

Comment: @javapowered I see.  I've submitted an answer showing the approach I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid calling a virtual method in the constructor, make a non-virtual private method, and call that from both the constructor and the virtual method:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        LoadVehicleParameters();
    }
    virtual void ReloadParameters()
    {
        LoadVehicleParameters();
    }
    private void LoadVehicleParameters();
    {
         //logic here.
    }
}
class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car() // call to base constructor is implicit
    {
        LoadCarParameters();
    }
    virtual void ReloadParameters()
    {
        base.ReloadParameters();
        LoadCarParameters();
    }
    private void LoadCarParameters();
    {
         //logic here.
    }
}
```

If your base class has no parameterless constructor, or if it has more than one constructor, you'll need to specify which base constructor to call, of course, like this:

```
public Car(int i) : base(i)
//...
```